# Fix uncrustify formatting for lambda expression

Tags: lambda, uncrustify

I would like to homogenize *Qt Creator* and [uncrustify](https://github.com/bengardner/uncrustify) formatting for lambda expression.

Writing the following code with *Qt Creator* produces the following format:

```
connect(this, &MyObject::mySignal, [&] {
    qDebug() << "test lambda uncrustify formatting";
});
```

But when formatting the code with *uncrustify* I have the following result:

```
connect(this, &MyObject::mySignal, [&] {
            qDebug() << "test lambda uncrustify formatting";
        });
```

Is there an *uncrustify* option that align the code like my *Qt Creator* example?

Comment: Not yet unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to fix it with the latest version of uncrustify.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for `indent_align_paren=false`? At least, using that seems to give the expected results.

If that breaks non-lambdas... well, which of these does Qt Creator give you?

```
// (A)
connect(this, &MyObject::mySignal,
    functor);

// (B)
connect(this, &MyObject::mySignal,
        functor);
```

If it gives you (B), then `indent_align_paren=false` will not do what you want, and Qt Creator's formatting is... questionable. (In which case, I suppose you should file a feature request against uncrustify, or a bug report against Qt Creator.) If it gives you (A), then you want `indent_align_paren=false` for more than just lambdas.

Comment: I finally managed to fix it with the latest version of uncrustify